# Classify couples $(n,m)$ such that $m\mid 2n$ and $4n\mid m^2$

Tags: number-theory, integer-lattices

Is there a classification of all the couples of positive integers $(n,m)$ such that $m\mid 2n$ and $4n\mid m^2$? The couples are infinite and I think there is no bound on $m$. I want to know because I want to classify isotropic subgroups of the discriminant group of an even lattice of rank $1$.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: the second condition implies that $m$ is even.  If $a$ is a divisor of $\frac m2$ then $n=a\times \frac m2$ works, and conversely.  Just writing out the conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things are actually quite straightforward. Assuming that $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$ are both natural and that $4n|m^2$ we infer in particular that $2|4n|m^2$ whence by transitivity $2|m^2$ and thus $2|m$. This means we can write $m=2r$ for a certain $r \in \mathbb{N}$.

Turning now to the first divisibility relation we gather from $2r|2n$ that $r|n$, whereas the second divisibility relation reduces to $n|r^2$. This means that we have the expression $n=kr$, with $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and such that $k|r$ if $r \neq 0$.

To conclude, apart from the trivial pair $(m, n)=(0, 0)$ we have in general $(m, n)=(2r, kr)$, where $r \in \mathbb{N}^{\times}$ is arbitrary and $k|r$ is a divisor of $r$.